# Heroku + gunicorn not working (bash: gunicorn: command not found )

Tags: heroku, gunicorn

I successfully install gunicorn:

```
remote: -----> Removing .DS_Store files
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-19.0.0.tar.gz (382kB)
remote:        Installing collected packages: gunicorn
remote:          Running setup.py install for gunicorn
remote:        Successfully installed gunicorn-19.0.0
```

My Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn myapp:app --log-file=-
```

But the app crashes when deployed:

```
bash: gunicorn: command not found
```

I tried adding the heroku python buildpack, but no luck. If I roll back to a previous commit (where `requirements.txt` and `Procile` are both unchanged), it works:

```
heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `gunicorn myapp:app --log-file=-` 
app/web.1:  2015-10-08 17:04:18 [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:51854 (3)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue seemed to fix itself after uninstalling all requirements remotely, and reinstalling them.

Comment: Deploy an empty requirements file, then deploy the original one.

Comment: An empty requirements file give me: "You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")"

Comment: Patrice good warning, I ran into this too so I'm going to remove all but the first from my requirements file.

Comment: This is such a cryptic solution!

Comment: @maxko87 You are right about emptying the requirements, it build the app, but nevertheless it crashes again in my case when pushing the full requirments

Comment: uploading empty or fresh copy of requirements.txt worked on my side.

Comment: @maxko87 can you specify the steps in your answer, how to uninstall requirements remotely?

Answer (score 143):

Make sure `gunicorn` is in your `requirements.txt`

Comment: It is there, notice the `remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))` in my question. Thanks though.

Comment: Try recreate your App in heroku.

Comment: I recreated it, same issue.

Answer (score 17):

I was missing the heroku/python buildpack
so I went to the dashboard and:

```
Settings -> Add buildpack -> heroku/python
```

Answer (score 17):

install `gunicorn` in your virtual environment

```
pip install gunicorn
```

then update your `requirements.txt` file

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: I transitioned to poetry and forgot to install gunicorn because it is only relevant when deploying.

Answer (score 12):

If you have both requirements.txt and Pipfile in the project root, then I would recommend to delete the Pipfile and have all your requirements listed in requirements.txt file (including gunicorn).

It will then show: "Installing requirements from pip", and all of your requirements listed in requirements.txt will be installed.

Answer (score 4):

Heroku's Python docs seem to be outdated... Apparently they now prefer a Pipfile over `requirements.txt`, but thankfully you can easily generate one with `pipenv`.

Try this:

`$ pip3 install --user pipenv` to install pipenv

`$ pipenv install gunicorn` to add gunicorn to the pipfile

`$ pipenv shell` to activate

I had the exact same error, and this worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

After checking that `gunicorn` is in `requirements.txt` run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My output contained several `Requirement already satisfied: ...` but `gunicorn` wasn't installed:

```
Collecting gunicorn (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Using cached ...

Installing collected packages: gunicorn
Successfully installed gunicorn-19.9.0
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, there was a conflict since I had `Pipfile`, `Pipfile.lock` and `requirements.txt` files all at once in the same directory / project.

Heroku was not installing anything from `requirements.txt`, hence the same gunicorn error as everyone here.

Answer (score 1):

add gunicorn in requirements.txt solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, even though gunicorn was in requirements.txt, gunicorn was not installing because of the Pipfile present.  I removed the Pipfile from my github repository and redeployed with success.

The following short tutorial was also helpful to make sure I had the essentials of runtime.txt, wsgi.py, and Procfile configured correctly.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deploy-python-flask-app-on-heroku/

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem but after adding
`gunicorn===<latest-version>` to requirements.txt file it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

install gunicorn in your virtual environment

```
pip install gunicorn
```

then update your requirements.txt file

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Add file to github

```
git add .
```

Commit

```
git commit -m "Added gunicorn"
```

Push back to heroku

```
git push heroku branch_name:main
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an issue inside 'Procfile'.
I removed `:` after `gunicorn`.

`web: gunicorn: app:app -> web: gunicorn app:app`

Answer (score 0):

You also need to be sure that when running your `git push heroku master` that the requirements are installed from requirements.txt and not from pipfile or pipfile.lock. So make sure you remove these files from you cd directory if you are installing your dependencies with requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because in `Pipfile` `gunicorn` was under the `dev-packages`. Installing it as regular package worked. Only with `Pipfile`. No `requirements.txt` necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it worked, but I was having the same issue, and after reading other suggestions, I ended up deleting my requirements.txt file (even though it had gunicorn) and running `pip freeze > requirements.txt` again and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my Heroku app was missing a python buildpack and thus **not installing any package**.

I fixed this by adding one : `Settings` > `Buildpacks` > `Add buildpack` > `python`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked for me

1. delete gunicorn from requirements.txt
2. $ pip3 install --user pipenv to install pipenv
3. $ pipenv install gunicorn to add gunicorn to the pipfile
4. $ pipenv shell to activate
5. push

Answer (score -1):

it happens when gunicorn is Not installed properly...
and for insatlling again, installor can only install a file if there is change in requirments.txt

so follow below steps :-

first, install a Empty or only one thing in requirments.txt
will make the installor to install something becoz there is change in requirments.txt and follow full complete setps after like git inti .... so on

after that repeat the all steps with full requirments.txt file
it will work surely....

mine solved this way..
thanks