# "No module named 'django_heroku' " app won't start on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

Trying to push to the heroku server, I get this:

```
git push heroku master

remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.7.3
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:
remote: -----> Downloading NLTK corpora…
remote:  !     'nltk.txt' not found, not downloading any corpora
remote:  !     Learn more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 206.4M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v10
remote:        https://versally.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

However, when I go to my app, it tells me there's an error. When I check in on the logs, I see this:

```
2019-04-30T13:22:00.633794+00:00 app[web.1]: import django_heroku
2019-04-30T13:22:00.633801+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
2019-04-30T13:22:00.634020+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-04-30 13:22:00 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-04-30T13:22:00.789044+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-04-30 13:22:00 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

I'm yet to setup the database, but I'm just looking to get a debug message from the django code so I can start with configuration of the database.

Comment: Add `django-heroku` to your `requirements.txt` or pipenv.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python

Comment: It's in there. I'd have posted it but StackOverflow said it was spam.

```

Comment: django-heroku==0.3.1

Comment: The thing is - the log says 'line 175' and I don't have a line 175 in my code,

Comment: File "/app/versal/settings.py", line 175, in <module>
2019-04-30T13:22:00.633794+00:00 app[web.1]: import django_heroku

Comment: My settings.py runs out at 172

Comment: I followed the deploying-python tutorial, but with my own app. I may try from their own git project, but I don't want to deploy their git project I need to deploy mine.

It does say this at the bottom:

Comment: Process exited with status 127
2019-04-30T14:15:47.995778+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2019-04-30T14:15:52.503801+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=versally.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 1):

For anyone out there with this problem, I solved it by emptying my requirements.txt, pushing (which forces Heroku to uninstall all the requirements) then pushing populated requirements through aggain.

I had to make sure gunicorn was included in requirements - which it was, but a log showed that for some reason heroku uninstalled my 'stale' version.

[Heroku + gunicorn not working (bash: gunicorn: command not found )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021874/heroku-gunicorn-not-working-bash-gunicorn-command-not-found)